# How to choose gRPC dependency versions between multi languages?

Tags: grpc

I am confused while using gRPC for multi languages(go, java).

The gRPC versions for each language seems to be related to each other(from release tags), but from the change logs of each release, different language implement seems not doing the same thing?

And the release tags for different languages are not one-to-one matched.

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to get to know? Does gRPC behave different with different languages?

Comment: @StimpsonCat Currently gRPC behaves good between different versions and different languages, I wonder whether it is a better idea to use the same version of gRPC for different languages.
for example how to choose gRPC versions for [grpc-go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/releases) and [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases)

Comment: Using the same version for different languages is recommended. Most gRPC features (documented as [gRFCs](https://github.com/grpc/proposal)) are designed with cross-language considerations and implemented/released in each language accordingly. Different languages should be able to interoperate seamlessly from consuming project's perspective. Different language implementations are developed separately, so each language has its own work log.